# Xpath query - Fields showing null

Tags: xpath, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2

I have the following CTE and XPath query that I'm having an issue with.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempXML') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempXML;

WITH ConvertedToXML AS 
( 
SELECT top 500 xml_msg AsVarchar
,status [status]
,date_received 
,CAST(xml_msg AS XML) AS AsXml
FROM interface_master_out
order by date_received desc
)

SELECT
ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//InstrumentID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS InstrumentID
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//MessageType)[1]', 'Varchar(10)') as MessageType
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//MessageID)[1]', 'Varchar(10)') as MessageID
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//date_received)[1]', 'datetime') as date_received
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//status)[1]', 'Varchar(10)') as [Status]
,ConvertedToXML.AsVarchar 
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml 
Into #TempXML
FROM ConvertedToXML
where ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//InstrumentID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') in ('BA1254890001');

select * from #TempXML
drop table #TempXML
```

date_received and Status are both coming up null and I can't figure out why. I've paired down the `in ( )` to a single value but there are really 30 of them.

Comment: You get the other values but not `date_recieved` and `status`? Please post the relevant part of the XML!

Comment: Maybe namespace related problem, but who knows for sure without XML sample that can demonstrate the problem..

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how I should proceed because the XML file is very large and contains confidential data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I played around with this enough, I was actually ridiculously easy. Below is the revised and working code:

```
Use MyDatabase
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempXML') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempXML;

WITH ConvertedToXML AS 
( 
SELECT top 50 xml_msg AsVarchar
,status Status
,date_received DateTime
,CAST(xml_msg AS XML) AS AsXml
FROM interface_master_out
order by date_received desc
)

SELECT
ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//InstrumentID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS InstrumentID
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//MessageType)[1]', 'Varchar(10)') as MessageType
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//MessageID)[1]', 'Varchar(10)') as MessageID
,ConvertedToXML.Status
,ConvertedToXML.DateTime
,ConvertedToXML.AsVarchar
,ConvertedToXML.AsXml 
Into #TempXML
FROM ConvertedToXML
where ConvertedToXML.AsXml.value('(//InstrumentID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = ('BA1254890001')

select * from #TempXML
drop table #TempXML
```